# How to convert a Visual Studio 2008 solution/project file that uses Intel Visual Fortran to compile with G95?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, fortran, intel

Im completely new to visual studio and don't really know the ins and outs of it.

I have a visual studio project which uses the Intel Visual Fortran compiler. However, my evaluation version of this compiler ran out and it is way too expensive for me to buy.

Is there a way I can change the project/make/solution file to run with the free fortran compiler G95. Also, how do I integrate G95 to work with Visual Studio as well? I ask this because the code has parts that are in C++ which also need to compiled at the same time.

I know this sounds like a wired question. I appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: It is definitely not trivial if possible at all. There are solutions which use the gfortran compiler with different IDEs (e.g., Photran). Or learn to use the command line tools and a text editor, as I do.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/202653

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had a feeling what I wanted would be difficult.  

Is there a way to compile the Fortran part of the code using gFortran, then link the output of the compiled Fortan code to the make/solution file for Visual Studio, so that when I build the project in Visual Studio, it compiles the C++ part and adds the pre-compiled fortran part to it?